# Ruby on rails Simple Search not displaying results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey guys im developing a rails application that stores quotes in a database and then allows you to search through the quotes using a simple search. I have implemented the search form but the results do not appear and I cant figure out why.

controller:

```
class BasicsController < ApplicationController
  def quotations
    @quotations = Quotation.all
    if params[:search]
      @quotations = Quotation.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @quotations = Quotation.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    if params[:quotation]
      @quotation = Quotation.new( params[:quotation] )
      if @quotation.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Quotation was successfully created.'
        @quotation = Quotation.new
      end
    elsif
      @quotation = Quotation.new
    end
    if params[:sort_by] == "date"
      @quotations = Quotation.order(:created_at)
    else
      @quotations = Quotation.order(:category)
    end
  end
end
```

model:

```
class Quotation < ApplicationRecord
  def self.search(search)
    where("author_name LIKE ? OR quote LIKE ?", "%#{search}", "%#{search}")
  end
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_tag basics_quotations_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search    Quotations" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
<h3>Quotations</h3>
<ul>
<% for quotation in @quotations %>
  <li><%= h quotation.author_name %>: <%= h quotation.quote %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<br/>
<% if params[:sort_by] == "date" %>
<%= link_to "Sort by category", :action => :quotations, :sort_by =>    :category %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Sort by date", :action => :quotations, :sort_by => :date %>
<% end %>
<hr/>

<h3>New quotation</h3>
<%= form_for @quotation, :url => { :action => :quotations } do |form| %>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter details</legend>
  <div class="form_row">
    <%= form.label :author_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :author_name, :size => 20, :maxlength => 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="form_row">
    <%= form.label :category %>
    <% @cats = [] %>
    <% Quotation.select('DISTINCT category').map(&:category).each do |element| %>
        <% @cats << element %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form.select(:category,options_for_select([[@cats[0],1],[@cats[1], 2], [@cats[2],3]])) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form_row">
    <%= form.label :new_category%>
    <%= form.text_field :category , :size =>20 , :maxlength => 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="form_row">
    <%= form.label :quote %>
    <%= form.text_area :quote, :rows => 2, :cols => 40, :maxlength => 500 %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
<div class="form_row">
  <%= form.submit 'Create' %>
</div>
</p>
<% end %>
```

routes:
    `Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'basics/quotations'
      resources :quotation, :quotations
      # For details on the DSL available within this file, see    http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
     end`

Comment: If you execute the search on the rails console: any results? Does the SQL generated by Rails look OK? 
When you just return ```Quotation.all``` instead of the search?

Your controller action mixes searching and creation of the quote. I'd separate that in two actions.

You can remove the first `@quotations = Quotation.all`

Comment: You were right about mySql query being wrong syntax. I also created a seperate action just to search the database. Thanks for taking time to reply to my question

Answer (score 0):

You've got EVERYTHING in one action, which isn't great. You might want to review some of the simple rails tutorials available.

On the subject of `search` in particular, note the last four lines of your method...

```
if params[:sort_by] == "date"
  @quotations = Quotation.order(:created_at)
else
  @quotations = Quotation.order(:category)
end
```

So regardless of the results of your seach, you'll replace `@quotations` at that point with all quotations in either `created_at` or `category` order.

Comment: Yeah after doing some more reading I was able to create a seperate action just to search the database for the quotations. I also had to change mySql query and then I got it to work. Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question

Answer (score 0):

It is not wise to place all the stuffs into a single action,your action should be very clear and well defined.But you can achieve what you wanted to do like this.

```
class BasicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :new_quotation, only:[:search_quotations,:index,:quotations]

  def search_quotations   
    respond_to do |format|

      if params[:search]
        @quotations = Quotation.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
      else
        @quotations = Quotation.all.order("created_at DESC")
      end

      if params[:sort_by] == "date" && quotations.present?
        @quotations = @quotations.order(:created_at)
      else
        @quotations = @quotations.order(:category)
      end         
      format.js{}
    end
  end


 def quotations 
   if params[:quotation]
     @quotation = Quotation.new( quotation_params)
     if @quotation.save
       flash[:notice] = 'Quotation was successfully created.'             
     end    
     redirect_to root_path
   end       
 end

 def index 
   @quotations = Quotation.all       
 end


 private:      

  def  new_quotation
   @quotation = Quotation.new
  end

 //If you are using rails4 for later version then go for this line.
 def quotation_params
   params.require(:quotation).permit(:author_name, :quote,:category)
 end

end
```

You need to actually separate the logic into above actions and where 'quotation' action is meant for creating a new quotation and 'seach_quotation' is for searching all the quotations and it should returns js response cause we are going to need this while rendering a partial '_list.html.erb'.

Your view(index.htm.erb) will be looking like this.

```
  <div>
   <%= form_tag basics_search_quotations_path, :method => 'get', remote: true do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search    Quotations" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
   <% end %>
 </div>
  #This partial will be used for refreshing the quotations list via remote true feature for searching and sorting.
  <div id="quotation_list">
    <%= render 'basics/shared/list',{quotations: @quotations} %>
  </div>
 br/>
 <% if params[:sort_by] == "date" %>
   <%= link_to "Sort by category", :action => :search_quotations, :sort_by => :category, :remote => true %>
 <% else %>
   <%= link_to "Sort by date", :action => :search_quotations, :sort_by => :date, :remote => true %>
  <% end %>
 <hr/>

 <h3>New quotation</h3>
   <%= form_for @quotation, :url => { :action => "quotations", :controller => "basics" } do |form| %>
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Enter details</legend>
       <div class="form_row">
         <%= form.label :author_name %>
         <%= form.text_field :author_name, :size => 20, :maxlength => 40 %>
       </div>
       <div class="form_row">
         <%= form.label :category %>    
         <%=     form.select(:category,options_for_select(['Love','Romance','Sadness'])) %>
       </div>
       <div class="form_row">
         <%= form.label :category%>
         <%= form.text_field :category , :size =>20 , :maxlength => 40 %>
       </div>
       <div class="form_row">
         <%= form.label :quote %>
         <%= form.text_area :quote, :rows => 2, :cols => 40, :maxlength => 500 %>
       </div>
   </fieldset>
  <p>
   <div class="form_row">
     <%= form.submit 'Create' %>
   </div>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the partial that display the list of Quotations /basics/shared/_list.html.erb

```
  <h3>Quotations</h3>
  <ul>
    <% for quotation in @quotations %>
      <li><%= h quotation.author_name %>: <%= h quotation.quote %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Here is the routes you need to add routes.rb

```
 resources :quotation, :quotations
 get "basics/search_quotations" => "basics#search_quotations"
 post "basics/quotations" =>  "basics#quotations"  
 root 'basics#index'
```

Instead of performing any calculation in views its better to perform it in  controller/model if needed.

so instead of this following line in your view

```
 <% @cats = [] %>
    <% Quotation.select('DISTINCT category').map(&:category).each do |element| %>
      <% @cats << element %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form.select(:category,options_for_select([[@cats[0],1],[@cats[1], 2], [@cats[2],3]])) %>
```

You can create an instance variable let's say @categories or something and  use it like this

```
  <%= form.select(:category,options_for_select(@categories)) %>
```

And last but not the least we have to have a search_quotations.js.erb because we are sending ajax request for fetching the search result and returning 'js' response.

```
   $("#quotation_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('basics/shared/list', {quotations: @quotations })) %>")
```